# How to get data from XML column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a `XML` column in a SQL Server database. I want to get results from that column. Here is what the XML column looks like:

```
<ArrayOfTarget xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes">
  <Target>
    <AgencyId i:nil="true" />
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id i:nil="true" />
    <Name>Quick Search</Name>
    <Type>Search</Type>
  </Target>
  <Target>
    <AgencyId i:nil="true" />
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id i:nil="true" />
    <Name>Quick Search = wbinc2000125</Name>
    <Type>Quick Search</Type>
  </Target>
  <Target>
    <AgencyId i:nil="true" />
    <AgencyName i:nil="true" />
    <Id i:nil="true" />
    <Name>Results (0)</Name>
    <Type>Result</Type>
  </Target>
</ArrayOfTarget>
```

Here are some things I have tried but no results:

```
select 
    [XML].value ('(ArrayofTarget/Target/Name/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Results
from 
    [DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

Another example:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (N'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as X)
SELECT
    [XML].value('(/X:ArrayOfTarget/X:Target/X:Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Name
FROM [DB].[dbo].[Table]
```

Comment: You're on the right track with `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, but the relevant namespace is the default namespace mentioned in `xmlns` (`http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes`). You can use [`DEFAULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces#specifying-default-namespaces) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example.

It shows how to handle properly a **default namespace** as well as how to use two XQuery methods: `.nodes()` and `.value()`

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<ArrayOfTarget xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes">
    <Target>
        <AgencyId i:nil="true"/>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id i:nil="true"/>
        <Name>Quick Search</Name>
        <Type>Search</Type>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <AgencyId i:nil="true"/>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id i:nil="true"/>
        <Name>Quick Search = wbinc2000125</Name>
        <Type>Quick Search</Type>
    </Target>
    <Target>
        <AgencyId i:nil="true"/>
        <AgencyName i:nil="true"/>
        <Id i:nil="true"/>
        <Name>Results (0)</Name>
        <Type>Result</Type>
    </Target>
</ArrayOfTarget>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TriTech.InformRMS.Domain.Core.ComplexTypes')
SELECT c.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Name]
    , c.value('(Type/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [Type]
FROM @tbl CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/ArrayOfTarget/Target') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------+
|            Name             |     Type     |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
| Quick Search                | Search       |
| Quick Search = wbinc2000125 | Quick Search |
| Results (0)                 | Result       |
+-----------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: I have many different XML results to pull from that one column. Would this example work with if the XML structure is the same in each cell but has different information?

Comment: @ITNoob, it should work. The dependency is on the XPath expressions only. As long as they are the same it will work.

Comment: @ITNoob, if the proposed solution is working for you, please don't forget to mark it as Answer.